# Can I create an operator in Tcl?

Tags: operators, tcl

I want to create a new operator in Tcl, by operator I mean a proc that could be used in the following way:

`$a**2` instead of `pow($a,2)`

Or in my case I want an operator that does the same as `<=` and `>=` but for floating point numbers, meaning:

```
proc <f= {a b {epsilon 1e-15} {
  if {$a < $b} {return 1}
  return [expr abs($a - $b) < $epsilon]
}
```

But I want to use it as:

```
if {$a <f= $b} {...
```

instead of"

```
if {[<f= $a $b]} {...
```

and the same for `>f=`

Comment: FWIW, Tcl 8.5 has a `**` operator that does exactly that (as long as one of the arguments is a float or the exponent is non-positive). But in general, no, there's no provision for new operators and it would be hard to change without yet another rewrite of the expression parser. User-defined functions are easy though, so long as you have 8.5 (or later).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't implement exactly this, but there is one option which might help.

Since Tcl 8.5, it's possible to define arbitrary *functions* for `expr` mini-language by creating *commands* in the [`tcl::mathfunc` namespace](http://wiki.tcl.tk/tcl::mathfunc), observe:

```
% set tcl::mathfunc::epsilon 1e-15
1e-15
% proc tcl::mathfunc::feq {a b} {
   variable epsilon
   expr {abs($a - $b) < $epsilon}
}
% expr { feq(1, 2) }
0
% expr { feq(1, 1) }
1
% expr { feq(1, 1 + 1e-16) }
1
% if {feq(1, 1 + 1e-16)} { puts OK } else { puts FAIL }
OK
```

And with a bit of [import/export](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/namespace.htm) mumbo-jumbo you can happily make this function be available as a command in your root namespace:

```
% namespace eval tcl::mathfunc { namespace export feq }
% namespace import tcl::mathfunc::feq
% feq 1 1
1
% feq 1 [expr {1 + 1e-10}]
0
% feq 1 [expr {1 + 1e-16}]
1
```

(Alternatively, you could create your command in any convenient namespace and then import it into the `tcl::mathfunc` namespace.)

Not exactly what you want, but comes close enough in my opinion.

Note also that since 8.5 Tcl has a special namespace [`tcl::mathop`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/tcl::mathop) which exposes all `expr` *operators* as commands, but you can't really modify this namespace in any way (but can use commands from it).

Comment: +1 this is a good option that I missed (not TCLed in anger for a while so I still think in 8.4)

Comment: You can modify the `tcl::mathop` namespace, but it won't let you create new operators like that; the namespace contains commands that expose the operators, but does not define them. The operators are defined directly in C code (notably the `expr` parser — `tclParseExpr.c` — and the bytecode execution core — `tclExecute.c`) so adding to them is currently _very_ non-trivial.

Answer (score 3):

TCL itself is strictly prefix notation so the superficial answer is no you can't ...

however you can also do some [radical things with unknown](http://wiki.tcl.tk/495) or you could implement your own version of something like [expr](http://wiki.tcl.tk/583) which can parse its arguments anyway it likes